# $.fancybox.close(); close all instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, instances

I use fancybox for status information, f.e. after succesfull login appear a box with message and that box disappear after some time, the code looks:

```
<a href="#status" id="click-status"></a>
<div id="status" class="status">You were succesfully logged in</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#click-status").fancybox({
afterLoad  : function() { setTimeout("$.fancybox.close();", 4000); },
helpers    : {
overlay    : null
               }
}).trigger("click");
```

then on the site I check some information about user and if a user has not actived account, then appear new fancybox in iframe (I do not see the firt one that is ok), where is written: please active your account, settiemout is not defined. The code looks:

```
<a id="box-inactive-user" href="box-inactive-user.php"></a>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#box-inactive-user").fancybox({
"type" : "iframe",
}).trigger('click');
});
```

and now the problem: the function

```
afterLoad  : function() { setTimeout("$.fancybox.close();", 4000); }
```

defined in first instance close all two instances! I do not want first instance hide all other fancybox instances. Is there a way, that fancybox code close only the instance in which is defined?

Thanks for solution

Comment: what I see is that `$("#click-status").fancybox()` is not wrapped inside the `.ready()` method (as the second one), other than that it should work properly. See http://jsfiddle.net/xM8Mh/ PS. I would use `afterShow` instead (cause you may actually want the box to be shown 4 seconds, otherwise any delay while opening may cause to close it sooner)

Comment: Thank you for solving, afterShow is the key.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the version of fancybox you are using.

For Fancybox 4 you can use `Fancybox.close();`